# What is correct way of injecting a nullable entity parameter in symfony5?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, parameters, entity, symfony5

Whenever I want to use an entity as a parameter (in this case SupportType) this is the quickest way:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new/{type}", name="app_support_case_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request, SupportCaseRepository $supportCaseRepository, SupportType $type = null): Response
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $now = new \DateTime();

    $supportCase = new SupportCase();
    $supportCase->setEmail($user->getEmail());
    $supportCase->setDateCreated($now);
    $supportCase->setMinutesSpent(0);
    $supportCase->setPublic(0);

    if($type != null) {
        $supportCase->setSupportType($type);            
    }
```

however there is a security issue here, because whenever no parameter is passed, symfony just picks the first random instance of the SupportType (as if it did a ->findAll() on the repository and picked the first one).

What is going on here?

It will never turn up as null even when I expect it to, i e when my route stops at /new and there is definately no parameter passed.

Instead I end up having to go through this hassle below whenever I want a parameter to actually be null if nothing is passed:

```
/**
 * @Route("/new/{type}", name="app_support_case_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request, SupportCaseRepository $supportCaseRepository, SupportTypeRepository $supportTypeRepository, $type = null): Response
{
....................................
    if($type != null) {
        $supportType = $supportTypeRepository->findOneBy(array('id'=>$type));
        if (is_null($supportType)) {
            die('No type with that ID exist. Hey, are you trying to hack me?');
        } else {
            $supportCase->setSupportType($supportType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would say, do not use magic here. Just use $type as a string parameters and call the repository only if it is not null. 
It only add one line of code to your exemple and at least do one less request to database if it is null. 
I advise you to not use is_null() function, use null === instead.

Comment: The weird thing is, if you do not have the param {type} filled on your url, i mean when it stop to /new. 
The route shouldnt match